# Serving compressed files with Azure CDN and a CentOS vm

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I have a CentOS vm running on Azure. I have several WordPress sites on the vm and I am using Azure CDN. Is there a way to config the CDN to serve compressed content? Also, I'm using W3 Total Cache.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to configure the CDN to compress your files before serving them to clients. However, you can certainly compress your files when you upload them to you blob storage and therefore the CDN will serve files that have already been compressed. That's what I do, anyway. Here's a snippet of C# code that demonstrates how I compress my files before uploading them to my Azure blob storage:

```
var blobData = new byte[] { ... you data goes here ... };

var stream = new MemoryStream();
var zipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
zipStream.Write(data, 0, blobData.Length);
zipStream.Close();

var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("myaccountname", "mykey");
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("$root");

var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("mycompressedfile.txt");
blob.Properties.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer: 
All 3 Azure CDN providers; Verizon, Akamai and Microsoft support compressing resources on the endpoint to return to the client, based on Accept-Encoding request headers.
see documentation for further details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cdn/cdn-improve-performance#compression-rules

Resource must meet certain criteria, and the resource MIME type be expressly configured for compression.